# persistent live USB won't load

Tags: usb, live-usb, mkusb

I made a persistent live USB using mkusb and the process was successful. But when I tried to use it, it won't load and whaterevr option i choose gives me the same error massage:
erro disk hd 0,4 not found
alloc magic is broken
and it quits
what is the problem with it?

Comment: I need some information details in order to help you. Please tell me: 0. Which version of `mkusb`  you are using; 1. Which version (16.04 LTS or 18.04 LT S or ...?) of Ubuntu you are are running (and where you have installed mkusb; 2. Which linux distro and version that you want to make persistent live (to be precise, which iso file that you use; 3. Did you check with `md5sum` that the iso file was downloaded correctly?; Please tell me about the computer (brand name and model ).